# Imgur image removal request being ignored... Stack Exchange help unanswered

Tags: support, images, imgur

I requested Imgur to remove a copyrighted image on the Imgur website which was originally posted on Math Stack Exchange.

This request has been ignored for a long time now. This image has been removed from the Math Stack Exchange question but is still existing in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/... . Even the Stack Exchange help (contact form) has been unanswered yet. How to have this image removed?

Comment: What does the image look like?

Answer (score 2):

Imgur has its own [removal request form](https://imgur.com/removalrequest), please ask for removal of the images there.

If that doesn't work, the person owning the copyright should have a lawyer file something like a [DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) takedown notice. There's nothing else you can do as a normal user.

Comment: Imgur removal request has been ignored for long time now. I have mentioned in the edited question.

Comment: Well, it seems you did everything you could. I suppose it's somebody else's picture, he/she should contact a lawyer to get it removed from imgur then.

Comment: @hijam Stack Exchange doesn't own imgur. Asking here won't do anything. We can't delete the image. If they have ignored you, you need to keep asking **them**.

Comment: @Catija: But SE *does* maintain the SE imgur account, and *can* and *will* delete images from it if necessary, per dupe and its dupe master.

Comment: Imgur requires a  registered copyright on the image to remove it. I do not own a registered copyright of the image but as the creator of the image I hold the non-registered copyright isn't it?. As I uploaded the image I must have the right to remove it as well, or do I not?.